# Putting in the dear

Tags: word-usage

> In her younger days Francesca had been known as the beautiful Miss
>   Greech; at forty, although much of the original beauty remained, she
>   was just dear Francesca Bassington. No one would have dreamed of
>   calling her sweet, but a good many people who scarcely knew her were
>   punctilious about putting in the “dear.”

[THE UNBEARABLE BASSINGTON CHAPTER 1](http://haytom.us/the-unbearable-bassington-chapter-1/)

Why did the people who **scarcely** knew her were punctilious about putting in the “dear”? I think the people who know her usually put in the dear.

Comment: Because she was beautiful. You don't have to know someone well to know they are beautiful. That's the point of the passage.

Comment: As she grew older, the epithet shifted from physical beauty to personality.  **dear** does not imply any close familiarity. It is a  bland epithet. If it has any bite to it, it is because of what it is not, namely, an epithet about her looks.

Comment: BTW, that story is written in clear but nuanced prose that would prove difficult for many university undergraduates whose first language is English.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: You're not kidding! *Her enemies, in their **honester** moments, would have admitted that she was svelte...* Personally, I've been a Saki fan for half a century, but its not exactly "current English for the masses".

Comment: Oh our wacky Saki—still stirring the pot from the crypt. How this would please him!

Answer (score 1):

That's the point. She was so sweet that not only her close friends, but even people who scarcely knew her, called her "dear". It's like saying, "Even his enemies called him an honest man".